# How do you setup automated-tests for Capacitor native apps?

Tags: ionic-framework, automated-tests, native, capacitor

`Capacitor` allows us to code once then generate web, `Android` and `iOS` applications. Most people using `Capacitor` will generate native `Android` and `iOS` applications.

But strange enough, I can't find any documentation about how to create automated-tests for the two `native` applications. I can easily test the web application using `protractor`, `jasmine` or whatever. But when it comes to native apps, I can't hardly rely on native tooling (`Android Studio` and `XCode`) as there are other issues preventing me from testing it easily (ex: no possibility to set Accessibility ID through the views markup, etc).

Where are we at with Capacitor native apps automated-tests ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for [**Ionic/capacitor Integrations for Testing**](https://ionicframework.com/integrations/category/testing)

As far as the community/forums and official docs go there are only 3 ways you can test your apks

1. Native [Andriod Studio / Xcode] [Emulated versions]
2. Real Devices
3. 3rd party Integration listed in the link above..

Even on google there very less info on this topic.. most of the blogs/ articles only say that Ionic/Capacitors can be tested just like a normal WEB App